# Brightness with AMD/Intel open source drivers Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati, xorg, brightness, hybrid-graphics

I have an issue with the screen brightness of my computer. I have a Dell Inspiron 7520. I have a AMD Radeon HD 7730m 2gb with a Intel HD 4000, I am currently using the kernel lastest kernel from X-edgers I believe. 3.7 something like that. Anyways, this isn't the problem. I'm sure there's a way to change the level of brightness from the terminal, or even just change the range, cause it looks the be range that isn't enough. In fact, when I try to lower the brightness, it drops but slightly but it doesn't go lower on the bar. If I want to make the screen go brighter, well it can't because it is at the max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try this link http://www.refreshit.info/2012/08/solved-brightness-increase-and-decrease.html
I have fixed the brightness problem ..

Comment: it doesn't work for my model, I am getting errors. I don't have the same line than you also. instead of splice I got splash. I have tried to change it. it doesn't do any good. but it works, not good enough though for me.

Answer (score 0):

this is unfortunately no answer to your problem, but i have the same laptop model and i also tried out the 3.7 kernel, because i have problems with the fan which is all the time running at full speed (did you solve that?). i experienced the same thing with the brightness. i swiched back to the 3.5 kernel. there it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I solved the fan part with a few script I found in here   http://askubuntu.com/questions/251705/dell-7520-inspiron-15r-se-fan-on-full-speed-on-12-04-12-10-13-04  I have also solved the brightness control using the last AMD drivers which allows me to use the switching too